# Bluetooth Headphone

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I have a bluetooth dongle I use with my laptop. However I have issues trying to connect my bluetooth headphones.

When I tried to pair them with my laptop, I clicked on the wrong option and my headphones are not visible/discoverable anymore. They still work correctly with my phone and other devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to clear all of the bluetooth settings, cache, and paired device on your Ubuntu machine

```
sudo rm -fr /var/lib/bluetooth/*
reboot
```

This answer came from:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=799329

I've tested this on Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10

Comment: thank but not worked for me. i also have tried  ;to reinstall  ubuntu (for other  reasons) / was formatted , but  the problem still remain.

Comment: Is ubuntu able to discover bluetooth devices? Try to connect your phone to your ubuntu laptop.